# Mink/behat iframe without id/name

Tags: iframe, behat, mink, setattribute

I have to verify text/messages inside an iframe wihout a name/id. After exploring, I found out that solution to add id/name and use switchToIFrame(id/name). How can I set id/name to a node element in mink? SetAttribute() is not a supported method in nodelement and setValue()  is not supported for a frame.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="div1">
    <iframe class="xyz">
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <body>
          <div class="frame"></div>
          <p>The paragraph1</p>
        </body>
       </html>
  </body>
</html>
```

My context file is

```
public function iShouldSeeDescription($arg1)
{
    $expected = "The paragraph1";
    $iframe=$this->getSession ()->getPage ()->find ( 'xpath', '//div[contains(@class,"div1")]/iframe[contains(@class,"xyz")]');
    $iframe->setAttribute('id', 'iframe_id');
    $iframeId = $iframe->getAttribute('id');
    $this->getSession()->switchToIframe("$iframeId");
    $actual = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('xpath', '//div[@class="frame"]/p[1]');
    if ($actual === null) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException ( sprintf ( 'null:%s', $arg1 ) );
    }
    if (!($actual === $expected)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException ( sprintf ( 'The Acutal description:%s and expected description:%s did not match ', $actual, $expected ) );
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume that this is just a method for test, else switch to iframe and validation should be different steps and the expected text and the selector containing this text should be parameters of the metod.

Answer (score 5):

What you could do to set id/name to an iframe is to use javascript.

Create a method like switchToIFrameBySelector($iframeSelector) that waits for the given element to be available then you can execute a javascript code to set a name/id for your iframe and after use switchToIFrame method.

For executing the js script you can use executeScript method in a try-catch and throw a custom Exception if needed.

```html
public function switchToIFrame($iframeSelector){

        $function = <<<JS
            (function(){
                 var iframe = document.querySelector("$iframeSelector");
                 iframe.name = "iframeToSwitchTo";
            })()
JS;
        try{
            $this->getSession()->executeScript($function);
        }catch (Exception $e){
            print_r($e->getMessage());
            throw new \Exception("Element $iframeSelector was NOT found.".PHP_EOL . $e->getMessage());
        }

        $this->getSession()->getDriver()->switchToIFrame("iframeToSwitchTo");
    }
```

Another way to set the id/name of the element in js is to use:

```js
setAttribute('name', 'iframeToSwitchTo')
```

Comment: I found this solution from your other Stackoverflow answers. Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Without using js/jQuery i don't think so. I see that there is a method setValue that points in Selenium2Driver which uses also a js script.Maybe there are no methods to change the page/element because you should't do these type of changes, setValue is for setting the value for text field/inputs. Do you have any restriction of using js? you should only interact with the page and not change it, using js is a work around for special circumstances.You should talk with a dev from the project to add some attributes if possible.

Comment: I will try to use this solution and see my if issue is solved. I will also post my code after I'm successful in this. Thank you!

Comment: Works great, Thank you.

Comment: public function iSwitchToIframe($arg1)
 {
  $function = <<<JS
   (function(){
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (var i=0; i < frames.length; i++) {
      if (frames[i].className == "blah") {
      frames[i].name = "iframeToSwitchTo";
     }
    }
     
    
   })()
JS;
  try{
   $this->getSession()->executeScript($function);
   $this->getSession()->getDriver()->switchToIFrame("iframeToSwitchTo");
  }
  catch (Exception $e){
   throw new \InvalidArgumentException ( sprintf ( "caught exception: %s", $e->getMessage()));
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

put the number or a for loop to iterate which one is required then set the number works with the cross origin

$this->getSession()->getDriver()->switchToIFrame(0);

Comment: Thats not how this method works. When you look into the implementation, the parameter must be a string which is used to search for the named iFrame. This solution would cause an error.